# Measuring transfer speed of USB drive

Tags: files, usb, benchmark

I want to write a program to find out the average data transfer speed of my USB port. How do I go about implementing it?

The only method I can think of is writing a large file to the path where the USB drive is mounted and finding out the time for that process. Is there a better method than this?

Comment: [Linus Torvalds, Apr 11, 2012](https://plus.google.com/111049168280159033135/posts/8emFkgB1kVS): 
«Greg - get [Jens' FIO](http://freecode.com/projects/fio) code. It does things right, including writing actual pseudo-random contents, which shows if the disk does some "de-duplication" (aka "optimize for benchmarks).
Anything else is suspect - forget about bonnie or other traditional tools.». FIO is open source and has some pretty good documentation, so I'd have a look at it.

Comment: Also the USB protocol has an overhead which needs to be considered. For example see ["Why are USB devices slower than 480 MBit/s"](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/24700/13371) from the Electronics SE.

Answer (score 2):

USB2 can reach speeds of 480Mbit/Sec in theory.  That equates (very roughly) to 60Mbytes/Sec.  If you HDD can't keep up with that sort of speed then you will get erronous results.

One option would be to buy/borrow a USB Ethernet adapter that claims it can connect 1 Gbit/Sec.  Connect it to another machine with a 1Gbit/Sec Ethernet port via a swapover cable or a 1Gbit/Sec hub/switch.

Run `nc -v -l -p 5000 > /dev/null` on one machine.  This will listen on port 5000 and send everything it receives to `/dev/null`.  This way there is no HDD involved.

On the other, run `time yes|nc -v a.b.c.d 5000 >/dev/null` (where `a.b.c.d` is the IP address of the far machine).  This will send `y` to the far machine until it is stopped at which point it will print the amount of data sent and `time` will print the time taken.

After a time period (eg 10 or 20 sec) stop the send by pressing `Ctl-C` and work out the speed. Remember that `nc` prints the amount of bytes sent, but you may need bits. `bits = 8 * bytes`

You may need to add more `-v`s to the commands so that you can see what's happening.